# Extract multiple lines from large text file with sed while preserving each trailing newline (Bash Script)

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, large-files

I have a large text file of several millions of line of which I need to extract specific lines.

Since I need to extract about 300000 lines (line numbers to be extracted are read from a file), I process them in batch of x lines (say 200) to speed up the process with the following command :

```
sed '1000p;1002p;2003p;...(200 times)...10001q;d' large_text_file >> extracted.txt
```

First I construct the string `1000p;1002p;2003p;...(200 times)...10001q;d`, then I call the `sed` command with the string as argument and repeat this until all lines are processed.

```
 sed_lines="1000p;1002p;2003p;...(200 times)...10001q;d"
 sed "$sed_lines" large_text_file >> extracted.txt
```

The problem I have is that the these 200 lines are now considered as one single line as `sed` does not keep the `\n` at the end of each line.

**Question 1**: Is there an option in sed for preserving the \n at the end of each line ?

**Answer 1**: Ok I figured this quickly after writing this post. Basically I missed the double quotes around `$sentences` in the line :

```
echo $sentences >> $forig.pseudo ==> echo "$sentences" >> $forig.pseudo
```

**Question 2: Is there a faster way to do this ?**

**Answer 2**: fedorqui's answer with `awk` is really fast and efficient

For the sake of comprehension, here is the bulk of script that does this process (edited with fedorqui's comment about the while):

```
echo "Extracting lines"
sed_lines=""
while IFS=$'\t' read -r linenr rest; do
        sed_lines+="$linenr"                   # Append line number
        ((cnt++))                              # Batch counter
        if [ "$cnt" -eq 200 ]; then
                sed_lines+="q;d"               
                sentences=$(sed "$sed_lines" $forig)   # Extract lines from file
                ((thres_cnt+=100))
                echo "$thres_cnt lines processed"
                echo $sentences >> $forig.pseudo       # Write lines to new file
                sed_lines=""
                cnt=0
        else
                sed_lines+="p;"
        fi
done < "$fperp"_cut_sorted
```

Comment: Oh my... the problem was just the missing double quotes around $sentences...

Comment: Note by the way that you can get the first word from every line saying `while IFS= read -r var1 var2; do` This way, `$var1` will contain the first word, `$var2` the rest.

Comment: @fedorqui When I try it everything is inside var1. EDIT: Ok. by chaging to IFS=$'\t' read -r, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using `awk` for this? Firstly store the line number in an array and then just keep checking if the line number of the file is in that array:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{line[$0]=$0; next} FNR in line' line_numbers file
```

#### Sample

```
$ cat line_numbers
8
16
4
6
9
$ cat file
1 hello
2 hello
3 hello
4 hello
5 hello
6 hello
7 hello
8 hello
9 hello
10 hello
11 hello
12 hello
13 hello
14 hello
15 hello
16 hello
17 hello
18 hello
19 hello
20 hello
$ awk 'FNR==NR{line[$0]=$0; next} FNR in line' line_numbers file 
4 hello
6 hello
8 hello
9 hello
16 hello
```

Comment: Well, I figured it quite quickly this time, I missed the double quotes around $sentences in  echo $sentences >> $forig.pseudo

Comment: I will try your solution to see if its faster !

Comment: @FloranGmehlin uhms, ok. However, I suggest you to give a try to this `awk` since it handles in a little line the full logic.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that I have to read the line number one by one as they are part of a 2 columns TSV file.

Comment: Ooooh, your solution works like a charm, and its way faster than mine =).
Thanks a lot!